# Updating an MS Teams card doesn't give an error on Android devices but doesn't display the updated card either

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to update a card for a Microsoft Teams Bot. In the web app this card is updated correctly but on Android devices this card doesn't update.

In this screenshots you can see the problem:
[image: First card sent]

This is the first card I send to the user and if the user clicks on "Reports" button it must update the card to this:
[image: Second card sent]

But on Android devices this card doesn't update:
[image: Second card in android devices]

I program this in NodeJS and use botframework 4.14.1.
I send the first card with `TurnContext.sendActivity` method and I update to the second card after the click with the `TurnContext.updateActivity` method.

The messages I send are:

```
{
   "type":"message",
   "inputHint":"acceptingInput",
   "attachments":[
      {
         "content":{
            "body":[
               {
                  "type":"ColumnSet",
                  "columns":[
                     {
                        "type":"Column",
                        "items":[
                           {
                              "url":"logo_img",
                              "size":"Small",
                              "type":"Image",
                              "style":"Person"
                           }
                        ],
                        "width":"auto",
                        "verticalContentAlignment":"Center"
                     },
                     {
                        "type":"Column",
                        "items":[
                           {
                              "size":"Large",
                              "text":"Hey, Pedro Clever! ",
                              "type":"TextBlock",
                              "wrap":true,
                              "weight":"Bolder"
                           },
                           {
                              "size":"Medium",
                              "text":"I’m your personal marketing assistant.",
                              "type":"TextBlock",
                              "wrap":true,
                              "spacing":"None",
                              "isSubtle":true
                           }
                        ],
                        "width":"stretch"
                     }
                  ],
                  "separator":true
               },
               {
                  "type":"Container",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "text":"I can do so much, send you **reports**, **graphs**, notify you with **alerts** and much more.",
                        "type":"TextBlock",
                        "wrap":true
                     },
                     {
                        "url":"https://i.imgur.com/IRv8FWf.gif",
                        "type":"Image",
                        "width":"318px",
                        "altText":"",
                        "horizontalAlignment":"Center"
                     },
                     {
                        "text":"With what do you prefer to start?",
                        "type":"TextBlock",
                        "wrap":true
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"history",
                        "type":"Input.Text",
                        "value":"[]",
                        "isVisible":false
                     },
                     {
                        "type":"ActionSet",
                        "actions":[
                           {
                              "id":"commandsTutorial",
                              "data":{
                                 "action":"commandsTutorial"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"Commands"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":"alertsTutorial",
                              "data":{
                                 "action":"alertsTutorial"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"Alerts"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":"reportsTutorial",
                              "data":{
                                 "action":"reportsTutorial"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"Reports"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":"shortcutsTutorial",
                              "data":{
                                 "action":"shortcutsTutorial"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"Shortcuts"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "type":"AdaptiveCard",
            "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "version":"1.0"
         },
         "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
      }
   ],
   "attachmentLayout":"list"
}
```

And the previous one is updated to this:

```
{
   "type":"message",
   "inputHint":"acceptingInput",
   "attachments":[
      {
         "type":"AdaptiveCard",
         "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
         "content":{
            "body":[
               {
                  "type":"ColumnSet",
                  "columns":[
                     {
                        "type":"Column",
                        "items":[
                           {
                              "url":"logo_img",
                              "size":"Small",
                              "type":"Image",
                              "style":"Person"
                           }
                        ],
                        "width":"auto",
                        "verticalContentAlignment":"Center"
                     },
                     {
                        "type":"Column",
                        "items":[
                           {
                              "size":"Large",
                              "text":"Hey, Pedro Clever! ",
                              "type":"TextBlock",
                              "wrap":true,
                              "weight":"Bolder"
                           },
                           {
                              "size":"Medium",
                              "text":"I’m your personal marketing assistant.",
                              "type":"TextBlock",
                              "wrap":true,
                              "spacing":"None",
                              "isSubtle":true
                           }
                        ],
                        "width":"stretch"
                     }
                  ],
                  "separator":true
               },
               {
                  "type":"Container",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "text":"1️⃣ How do scheduled reports work?",
                        "type":"TextBlock",
                        "wrap":true
                     },
                     {
                        "text":"2️⃣ How do recurring messages work?",
                        "type":"TextBlock",
                        "wrap":true,
                        "spacing":"Small"
                     },
                     {
                        "text":"3️⃣ What are Smart Reports?",
                        "type":"TextBlock",
                        "wrap":true,
                        "spacing":"Small"
                     },
                     {
                        "type":"ActionSet",
                        "actions":[
                           {
                              "id":"reportsFirst",
                              "data":{
                                 "step":0,
                                 "action":"reportsTutorialStep"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"1️⃣"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":"reportsSecond",
                              "data":{
                                 "step":1,
                                 "action":"reportsTutorialStep"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"2️⃣"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":"reportsThird",
                              "data":{
                                 "step":2,
                                 "action":"reportsTutorialStep"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"3️⃣"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"history",
                        "type":"Input.Text",
                        "value":"[\"reportsTutorial\"]",
                        "isVisible":false
                     },
                     {
                        "type":"Container",
                        "items":[
                           
                        ],
                        "isVisible":false
                     },
                     {
                        "text":"Continue with:",
                        "type":"TextBlock",
                        "wrap":true,
                        "isVisible":false
                     },
                     {
                        "type":"ActionSet",
                        "actions":[
                           {
                              "id":"commandsTutorial",
                              "data":{
                                 "action":"commandsTutorial"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"Commands"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":"alertsTutorial",
                              "data":{
                                 "action":"alertsTutorial"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"Alerts"
                           },
                           {
                              "id":"shortcutsTutorial",
                              "data":{
                                 "action":"shortcutsTutorial"
                              },
                              "type":"Action.Submit",
                              "title":"Shortcuts"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "version":"1.2",
         "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
      }
   ],
   "attachmentLayout":"list"
}
```

I had to delete the image urls to avoid the spam filter.

Comment: We checked this at our end in OnePlus 9R mobile. Card is getting updated successfully without any issue. Could you please let us know if this issue is specific to any Android model?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I tried on an Oppo Find N2 Flip and on a Xiaomi Mi 11

Comment: We will check this internally and get back to you.